# SQL One table - Current period cases

Tags: sql, netezza

We've table "LN DETAILS" has below data.

```
**ACTG PRD CASE ID DEC**
202004  101 Flexible
202003  105 Non Flexible
202004  106 Flexible
202003  101 Non Flexible
202004  109 Flexible
```

Now we want the cases where the desc is "Flexible" and added in current period and they shouldn't be in the previous period. Here CASE 101 is in CURRENT PERIOD 202004 and 202003. so we don't want this in result data
Here is the expected output:

```
**ACTG PRD CASE ID DEC**
202004  106 Flexible
202004  109 Flexible
```

[image: table]

Comment: Please at least display your attempted SQL query

Comment: What is SQL engine you are using? MySQL, Postgres, MS SQL Server, Oracle or something else. And what is datatype of that accounting period column? Varchar, some datetime-field or even integer?

Comment: Hello Its NETEZZA. Acccounting Period is INTEGER.

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to put spaces in your names whether table or column; nor should you use SQL Keywords, in your case column names like Case or DEC; rather use an underscore in place of the space. My answer though involves the needed brackets because of your spaces.

```
    Select * from [LN DETAILS] 
    where [LN DETAILS].[ACTG PRD]=(
            select Str(DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()),4)+ case when DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())<10 
            Then Str(0,1)+Str(DATEPART(mm,GETDATE()),1) 
            Else Str(DATEPART(mm,GETDATE()),2) end)
        and [LN DETAILS].[DEC]='Flexible'
```

Update from above to not return any Case_IDs that have one from the previous *ONLY* month. Insanely long because your dateField is text.

```
 Select * from [LN DETAILS] t1
 where not exists (
    select * from [LN DETAILS] t2 
    where t1.[Case ID]=t2.[Case ID]
    and t1.[ACTG PRD]=(
             select Str(DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()),4)+ case when DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())<10 
             Then Str(0,1)+Str(DATEPART(mm,GETDATE()),1) 
             Else Str(DATEPART(mm,GETDATE()),2) end)
    and t2.[ACTG PRD]=(
            select Str(DATEPART(yyyy,Dateadd(month,-1,getdate())),4)+ case when DATEPART(mm,Dateadd(month,-1,getdate()))<10 
             Then Str(0,1)+Str(DATEPART(mm,Dateadd(month,-1,getdate())),1) 
             Else Str(DATEPART(mm,Dateadd(month,-1,getdate())),2) end) )
 and t1.[ACTG PRD]=(
             select Str(DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()),4)+ case when DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())<10 
             Then Str(0,1)+Str(DATEPART(mm,GETDATE()),1) 
             Else Str(DATEPART(mm,GETDATE()),2) end)
 and t1.[DEC]='Flexible'
```

Comment: Thank you Edwrard. But I need the CASE IDS which are added in current period only. If the Case Id 's Status is already added in previous periods I don't need them in output. This is expected one **ACTG PRD CASE ID DEC**
202004  106 Flexible
202004  109 Flexible

Comment: And why don't you just keep [ACTG PRD] as a datetime? You storing it as text like that makes it that much harder to create sql against.